# get index value of numpy.ndarrays and do math on it in a one line condition

Tags: python, numpy

given the following numpy.ndarrays of identical length

```
nparray_upper = [ 5.2  4.9  7.6  10.1]
nparray_base =  [ 2.2  2.6  5.5  11.02]    
nparray_lower = [ 4.3  1.4  3.2  8.9]
```

and a fixed size variable

```
multiplier = 10
```

how do i multiply the index of each with the multiplier based on a condition?

```
indexMultiplierCondition = np.where(((nparray_base <= nparray_upper) & (nparray_base >= nparray_lower)), INDEX * multiplier, 0).sum()
```

the above should return

> indexMultiplierCondition = 30

because only **2.6** and **5.5** in nparray_base are within the upper and lower level and the sum of their index 1 and 2 multiplied by 10 is 30

this should be as efficient as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

np.where returns a tuple.

So, you can retrieve the first element of the tuple (which is a np.ndarray) and multiply by a scalar value of your choice.

For example,

```
i = np.where(((b<=a) & (c<=b)))
(array([1, 2], dtype=int64),)

i[0] * m
array([10, 20], dtype=int64)

(i[0] * m).sum()
30
```